# Joomla 3.x Search Engine Friendly URL for Articles

Tags: url, joomla, seo

I've got a website using Joomla 3.x.

There are 2 different categories and a few articles in each category. Let's assume the IA of the website is as follow:

- Home
- Category A (alias: cat-a)

  - Article 1 (alias: art-1)
  - Article 2 (alias: art-2)
- Category B (alias: cat-b)

  - Article 3 (alias: art-3)
  - Article 4 (alias: art-4)

Where "Home", "Category A" and "Category B" are menu items.

Therefore, I would expect when I visit Article 1, the URL would be something like:
http://www.example.com/cat-a/art-1
and it does happen.

However, with the same settings, it looks differently when visiting Article 3:
http://www.example.com/art-3

So the question is, how can I make the URL of Article 3 like that of Article 1?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation details and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, it would be better asked on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)